# How to write my own download manager using Objective C for iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, download-manager

I am writing a download manager for iPhone using objective C. I am using [ASIHTTP framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and its working great. But my problem is I am not able to download from file sharing sites like filesonic, rapidshare, hotfile etc.

I want to know how can I get download (actual download) url from these sites, or at least how these sites are hiding this info (and where), so I can get that somehow...

Is there any open source library or framework to help me with this? How firefox or other desktop browser get this link?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Update 1 : I don't want to bypass their advertising and revenue streams. Almost all file sharing companies also provide free downloads with low bandwidth, I only want to use that service. there are many download managers available now for iPhone like - "Downloads Lite". I just want to build a similar functionality.

Comment: I would suggest that if not freely available either through instruction from the download companies or via an open api then the companies probably won't be very happy with you providing access to their services and bypassing their advertising and revenue streams.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson - I don't want to bypass their advertising and revenue streams. Almost all file sharing companies also provide free downloads with low bandwidth, I only want to use that service. there are many download managers available now for iPhone like - "Downloads Lite". I just want to build a similar functionality.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't know much about Downloads Lite or any others. However, I'm sure downloads sites have the free option to entice users to either pay the full price, or click on their adverts. I think it might be worth looking into where you stand with the downloads companies, the last thing you want is for your app's service to be interrupted because they've cut off your access to their downloads or similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download from file sharing sites in iOS SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253936/how-to-download-from-file-sharing-sites-in-ios-sdk)

Comment: @jrturton - the possible duplicate does not have any answer.. thats why I posted this again.. and wow.. I got an answer.. you should not close this question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the end of your question:

> How firefox or other desktop browser get this link?

AFAIK, download managers intercepts downloads that are to start in a browser and manage them themselves. So, the link, and all the rest of requirements (cookies and so on) so that the download takes actually place, come from the browser.

I think you could follow the same approach:

1. use a `UIWebView` to browse to the content you would like to download;
2. intercept any change of page or download by defining [`– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) in your web view delegate;
3. in case it is a download of some supported content, return `NO` from `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` (so that the `UIWebView` does not do anything), and pass the address to your custom download manager to do the actual downloading.

In my experience, this will also maintain cookies (i.e., `UIWebView` and `ASIHTTP` will share them), but YMAMV.